# Trouble Linking Javascript code to html buttons on Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to emulate a jsfiddle on visual studio code. I basically want to be able to run this: https://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/aapne9nv/ on my own through vscode.

Here's the HTML code im using at the moment:

```
<h2>Form</h2>
<script src="Converter.js"></script>
<form id="myform" action="" method="post">
  First Name:
  <input type="text" name="Fname" maxlength="12" size="12" />
  <br/> Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="Lname" maxlength="36" size="12" />
  <br/> Gender:
  <br/> Male:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" />
  <br/> Female:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />
  <br/> Favorite Food:
  <br/> Steak:
  <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="Steak" />
  <br/> Pizza:
  <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="Pizza" />
  <br/> Chicken:
  <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="Chicken" />
  <br/>
  <textarea wrap="physical" cols="20" name="quote" rows="5">Enter             
your favorite quote!</textarea>
  <br/> Select a Level of Education:
  <br/>
  <select name="education">
    <option value="Jr.High">Jr.High</option>
    <option value="HighSchool">HighSchool</option>
    <option value="College">College</option>
  </select>
  <br/> Select your favorite time of day:
  <br/>
  <select size="3" name="TofD">
    <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
    <option value="Day">Day</option>
    <option value="Night">Night</option>
  </select>
  <br/> Range Slider:
  <input type="range" name="rangeslider" min="10" max="50" step="10"         
value="20" data-rangeslider="">
  <p>
    <input id="toJson" type="submit" value=" toJson " />
    <input id="toForm" type="submit" value=" FillForm " />
</p>
</form>
<h2>JSON</h2>
<pre id="result">
</pre>
```

And here is the javascript code:

```
$(function () {
$('#toJson').click(function () {
    var jsonify = $("#myform").jsonify({
        stringify: true
    });

    console.log(jsonify);
    $('#result').text(jsonify);
    return false;
});

/* Fill form populate */
$('#toForm').click(function () {
    $("#myform").dejsonify({
        "Fname": "Roger",
        "Lname": "Tremblay",
        "gender": "Male",
        "food": ["Steak", "Pizza"],
        "quote": "I am the best",
        "education": "HighSchool",
        "TofD": "Day",
        "rangeslider": "40"
    });

    return false;
});

});

!function (i) {
    alert();
    i.fn.jsonify = function (t) {
        var n = i.extend({ stringify: !1 }, t), s = {}
        return i.each(this.serializeArray(), function () { this.name in s ? (s[this.name].push || (s[this.name] = [s[this.name]]), s[this.name].push(this.value || "")) : s[this.name] = this.value || "" }), n.stringify ? JSON.stringify(s) : s
},
i.fn.dejsonify = function (t) {
    alert();
    "string" == typeof t && (t = JSON.parse(t)), i.each(this.find("*[name]"), function () {
        var n = i(this).attr("type"), s = t[i(this).attr("name")]
        "radio" === n || "checkbox" === n ? i.isArray(s) ? i(this).prop("checked", i.inArray(i(this).val(), s) > -1) : i(this).prop("checked", i(this).val() === s) : i(this).val(s)
    })
}
}(jQuery)
```

I've copied the html file and the javascript file into a folder and I've downloaded an extension that allows me to run the html just fine. I can interact with the page in my browser. However, when I click the "toJson" or "fillform" buttons it does not execute properly. What should happen is to have it print the json for the input I just provided underneath the form. Instead, it removes my input from the forms without providing the json form as it should. I can put "Alert()" into the javascript code and that will not even occur.

I totally recognize that me simply having the javascript code in the same workspace as the html will not allow the javascript to know when its functions are being called. I'm just pretty much brand new with this type of coding and don't know what I should be doing. Can someone help me out and explain what I need to be doing for the javascript functions to be getting ran?

Note: When I add the line `<script src="Test.js"></script>` into the html code, I can get an alert to show up on the page. (I made a 1 line js file called Test that just runs "Alert()". So I don't know if I have to do something similar with my actual javascript code or if it's something totally different.

Comment: You should include whatever error message(s) you're getting. Also, are you including jQuery? The fiddle you link to is using jQuery 3.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

yes. Link the same way like you did by providing the correct path.